# Google home not sending oath token with request

Tags: oauth-2.0, actions-on-google, google-authentication

I'm having an issue where when I ask a question via the physical google home the oath token is not being sent (using OAuth Account Linking) along the request. When I use the Google Assistant App on My iPhone the token is being sent along side the request. Via the Physical Google Home I am able to access the Skill etc.

Does anyone have any intuition as of why the token is being sent when using the Assistant App, The testing console ( on the actions console) but not in the physical google home ?

Comment: Can you give more information about your account linking details, and whether you've enabled voice match on your Google Home?

Comment: Voice match has not been enabled on the google home Authentication is done through azure active directory using auth codes (not implicit flow).  

To reiterate the token is being passed when using my iPhone google assistant app, and when using the testing tab in the developer console of google actions, but not when using the physical google home.

Comment: I'd enable voice match on the Google Home, as it's likely interpreting your Action activation as an anonymous user, not as you.